# Compressed and decompression column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do compress/decompress while storing in mysql. Does it affect the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it does. But it might be not as bad as you think depending on several factors like your Hardware, the Compression Method and several other things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, compressing/decompressing data require more processing time.